# Retrieving font name from font file in Java

Tags: java, api, fonts, truetype

Is there any Java API to get the font name from a font file (TTF)?

Answer (score 11):

Sure, the `java.awt.Font` class will handle this task just fine. Here's how:

```
Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));
String name = f.getName();
```

(I tried it on one of the ttf-fonts on my system and it works as intended.)